# Redis Sentinel with 2 App Servers and 1 Additional Sentinel Node Setup

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

We have 2 app/web servers running HA application, we need to setup redis with high availability/replication to support our app.

Considering the minimum sentinel setup requirement of 3 nodes.

We are planning to prepare the first app serve with redis master and 1 sentinel, the second app server will have the redis slave and 1 sentinel, we plan to add one additional server to hold the third sentinel node to achieve the 2 quorum sentinel setup.

Is this a valid setup ? what could be the risks ?

Thanks ,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks its not recommended to put the redis nodes on the app servers (where it is recommended to put the sentinel nodes there).

We ended with a setup for [KeyDB](https://github.com/JohnSully/KeyDB) (a fork from Redis) which claimed to be faster and support high availability/replication (and much more) to create two nodes within the app servers.

Of course We had to modify little in the client side to support some advance Lua scripts (There is some binary serialized data not getting replicated to the other node).

But after some effort, **it worked !**  as expected.

Hope this helps ...